# Hi, need to clarify this probability formula for P(B) compliment

Tags: probability

We know that P(B) compliment = 1 - P(B). Isn't this equal to P(A) - P(A and B) ? I asked this to chat gpt, and it said these are two different things, I didn't understand how it can be different.

If you think in a ven diagram for two events with P(A) and P(B), it would be the shaded portion as given below.

[image]

As you can see they both look same to me. This is the CHAT Gpt's response:
I asked this:

```
is P(B) compliment same as P(A) - P(A and B) ?
```

ChatGPT Replied this:

```
No, P(B^c) (the complement of event B) is not the same as P(A) - P(A ∩ B). The correct formula for P(B^c) is 1 - P(B). I appreciate your patience and apologize for any confusion in my previous responses.

To clarify:

The complement of event B is denoted as P(B^c) and is equal to 1 - P(B).
The expression P(A) - P(A ∩ B) represents the probability of event A occurring without the occurrence of event B. It does not directly represent the complement of event B.
So, the correct statement is P(B^c) = 1 - P(B), not P(B^c) = P(A) - P(A ∩ B). I hope this clears up any confusion.
```

This got me confused, I think Chat GPT is wrong here, but I want your help to clarify this, from real humans.

**Question**:
Question is Simple:
Is P(B) compliment = 1-P(B) = P(A) - P(A∩B) ?

Comment: For $B^c$, also colour everything outside the two circles green.

Comment: But isn't P(A) + P(B) = 1 ? why outside the circle matters?

Comment: Whether $P(A)+P(B)$ is $=1$ or $>1$ or $<1$ depends on the exact events $A$ and $B$.

Comment: What if they both are mutually exclusive ?, then is it true ?

Comment: If $A^c$ and $B^c$ both are mutually exclusive, then now they are the same: $$P(B^c) = P((B^c\cap A)\cup(B^c\cap A^c)) = P(B^c\cap A)$$.

Comment: Or maybe you would like an example? Throw a fair six-sided die once, let $A$ be the event that the outcome is $1$, and $B$ be that the outcome is $2$. Here $A^c$ and $B^c$ are *not* mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *peterwhy* mentioned in his comment, you have to consider the rest of the universal set, everything that lies outside $A$ and $B$.

Only when $A$ and $B$ together make the entire universal set, and hence, $P(A \cup B) = 1$,

$$\begin{align*}
P(B^c) &= 1 - P(B) \\[0.3cm]
&= P(A \cup B) - P(B) \\[0.3cm]
&= P(A) - P(A \cap B)
\end{align*}$$

In other situations, this equality won't hold.

Comment: Got it, this helps to clarify.